# How to secure my connection string? powershell + xml

Tags: xml, powershell, connection-string

I store my connection-string in XML file. Then i use it in powershell script. Is there a way to secure it/to encrypt it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods I've seen for encrypting in Powershell

[Use *SecureString cmdlet](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/04/08/encrypting-powershell-scripts.aspx)s. It should be noted only the Windows ID that encrypted the original string can decrypt it (since it uses the Windows login as key)

Use a pass phrase with the [Library-StringCrypto](http://lunex.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!64CB3857E28BD106!344.entry) functions

Because of the limitations of the first method, I use the second. I'll then store my encrypted connection string in a SQL table and lock down permissions. To make a connection I'll retrieve the connection string from the SQL table and decrypt using a pass phrase.

Comment: thank you. i very like the idea of storing connection string in sql table. but my supervisor doesnt like it.