# How to secure mysql connection with powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, encryption, credentials

I have a powershell function which connects to a mysql database. In this function there is a connection string which looks like this:

```
$ConnStr = "Server=server;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Database=DB";
```

Now whats the best way to store these information secure and not just have the string in plain text in the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure my connection string? powershell + xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183433/how-to-secure-my-connection-string-powershell-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a encrypted password that is specific to the PC the file is saved on using...

```
$folder = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")     
$passFile = "$folder\MyPass.txt"
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $passFile
```

Then when you need to retrieve the password and use it.

```
$passwdfolder = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")     
$passwdFile = "$passwdfolder\MyPass.txt.txt"
$securePasssword = Get-Content $passwdFile | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($null, $securePasssword,$null)
$MyPass = $credentials.Password
```

It's not perfect.  Anyone with access to the computer can get the password with a bit of know-how, but it's better than storing your password in plain text.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will look into that and test it.